# how can i strip word from a string in php

Tags: php, sql, trim

i am displaying the top 5 results from a sql query using the following code;

```
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT location, COUNT(location) AS qty FROM ecmt_memberlist GROUP BY location ORDER BY qty DESC LIMIT 0,5"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<span class='graphValue'>x".$row['qty']."</span> " .      $row['location'] . "<br />";

} ?>
```

this is displaying my result strings as follows:

- x46 Moon 20 - Sisters of EVE Academy
- x34 Moon 7 - Ammatar Fleet Assembly Plant
- x28 Jita x11 Jita IV - Moon 4 - Caldari Navy Assembly Plant
- x11 Jita IV - Moon 4
- x9 Lonetrek III - FUUUFAGOLAS

how can i trim down the $row['location'] to show the words before the first "-" for example;

- x46 Moon 20
- x34 Moon 7
- x28 Jita x11 Jita IV
- x11 Jita IV
- x9 Lonetrek III

Comment: `explode()` function maybe ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo explode('-', $row['location'])[0];
```

OR

```
echo preg_replace('/\-\s.+/i', '', $row['location']);
```

Comment: preg_replace('/\-\s.+/i', '', $row['location']); worked a treat, when i use strstr() it didnt display anything for "x28 Jita x11 Jita IV - Moon 4 - Caldari Navy Assembly Plant" just the x28.

Comment: yeah) you right) double "-" change situation))
Removed it.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) and print before needle, e.g.

```
strstr($row['location'], "-", TRUE);
```

Comment: If there's any possibility that the first part of the result could contain a hyphen, I'd recommend changing the second parameter to " - " (adding a space on either side.

Comment: OP may want to use `" -"` to filter out the space without another function call to `trim` - just a point of reference. ^^

Comment: A more robust solution may be to use a simple regular expression like `preg_replace('/ - .*/', null, $row['location'])`

Answer (score 3):

while you could do it with php as every on else suggest, i think its better to do it with mysql:

```
  $query = "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(location,'-',1) as location, COUNT(location) AS qty FROM ecmt_memberlist GROUP BY location ORDER BY qty DESC LIMIT 0,5";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str='x46 Moon 20 - Sisters of EVE Academy';

$str2=substr($str,0,strpos($str,' -'));

echo $str2;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple different ways you could do this, one using `explode()`

```
$location = explode("-", $row['location']);
```

Then call everything before the "-" with `echo $location[0];` See [PHP Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Or you can use `strstr()`

```
$location = strstr($row['location'], '-', true);
```

and call it with just `$location` as setting the 3rd parameter to true returns everything before the first occurrence of the 2nd parameter. See [PHP strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

Or you can use `split()`

```
$location = split("-", $row['location']);
```

and call it using `$location[0]`